# Not able to create instances on CloudStack

Tags: apache-cloudstack

I have created a Zone, Pod and Cluster on CloudStack.I have also added a host in the Cluster, added Primary Storage and Secondary Storage. But in System VMs, nothing is listed. Also, in the logs a message "No running ssvm is found, so command will be sent to LocalHostEndPoint" comes.

Somehow I deduced that due to this, template is not being added and consequently Instances can't be created as Instances use templates to add OS in VMs.

Can anybody please help to point out and sort the problem which may be the cause here.

Comment: After some thought, I feel this question should be posted on [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/), because it a setup issue rather than one involving programming.  Can you repost there?  If you drop the link into this question, I'll follow up.

Answer (score 1):

You need to manually install the "system VM" templates.  These are the images for worker VMs that CloudStack deploys to run system services.  SSVM is an example of a SystemVM.  It is responsible for copying templates to secondary storage.

See [Prepare the System VM Template](http://cloudstack.apache.org/docs/en-US/Apache_CloudStack/4.2.0/html/Installation_Guide/management-server-install-flow.html#prepare-system-vm-template) in the installation guide.

Comment: I  have followed the method to prepare the System VM template and it is mounted also as told in the guide.But when I click on System VM nothing is listed although it seems to be searching for existing VMs

Comment: Is the zone set to enabled?